# Problem while multiplying under a set of relators

Tags: gr.group-theory, computer-algebra, gap

I have defined $S_4$ (Symmetric group of order 4), and with the base field $Z_5$, groupring $Z_5S_4$ is constructed. Then I have taken two elements of this group ring and I want to multiply them to get the simplest result.

```
gap> f := FreeGroup( "a", "b","c" );;
gap> G := f / [ f.1^2, f.2^3,f.3^4, f.1*f.2*f.3 ];
<fp group on the generators [ a, b, c ]>
gap> AsList(G);
    [ <identity ...>, a, b, b^-1, c, c^-1, a*b^-1, a*c, b*a, b*c^-1, b^-1*c^-1, c*b^-1, c^2,
  c^-1*a, a*b^-1*c^-1, a*c*b^-1, b*a*b^-1, b*a*c, b^-1*c^-1*a, c*b^-1*c^-1, c^-1*a*c,
  a*b^-1*c^-1*a, b*a*b^-1*c^-1, b^-1*c^-1*a*c ]
gap> a:=G.1;;
gap> a^2;
a^2
gap> a^2=One(G);
true
```

**Question**
Why I am not getting simplified form of the group elements? E.g. `a^2` is the identity, but is displayed as `a^2`.

Comment: Please help the reader from the beginning by explaining what you're doing, instead of copying your code and just finish with a short sentence.

Comment: Please also be sure to post code as code; this was initially almost unreadable (even, presumably, to someone who knows GAP syntax as I don't).  I have edited accordingly.  This also looks much more like a technical GAP question than a math question ….

Comment: @YCor I am sorry for this. Do I need to explain every syntax ?

Comment: No, provide some guidelines about what you're doing

Comment: @YCor I have defined $S_4$ (Symmetric group of order $4$), and with the base field $Z_{5}$, groupring $Z_5S_4$ is constructed. Then I have taken two elements of this group ring and I want to multiply them to get the simplest result.

Comment: Please edit your post rather than comment?

Comment: The group ring is not relevant to this question. The question relates only to the finitely presented group $G$, so there was no need to mention the group ting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algorithms for finitely presented groups are hard -- generically problems, such as testing whether a word represents the identity (or finding a shortest word expression) do not have (they cannot exist as they are equivalent to the Halteproblem for Turing machines) general algorithmic solutions.
Therefore GAP will by default not reduce word expressions in finitely presented groups.

If you know that your group `G` is finite and small, you can force a reduction by issuing the following two commands **immediately** after creating the group:

```
Size(G);
SetReducedMultiplication(G);
```

Then, when the first product of generators is formed, GAP will calculate a confluent rewriting system using a Knuth-Bendix algorithm, and use it to bring elements in a lenlex-minimal representation. In your example you then will get:

```
gap> List(G);
[ <identity ...>, a, b, b^-1, c, c^-1, c^-1*b, a*c, b*a, b*c^-1, c*b, c*b^-1,
  c^2, c^-1*a, a*c*b, b*c^-1*a, b*c^-1*b, b*a*c, c*b*a, c^2*b, a^c, a*c*b*a,  b*a*c*b, c^-1*a*c*b ]
gap> a:=G.1;;
gap> a^2;
<identity ...>
```

This however costs time and memory (and for large groups might not be able to succeed), and is not always necessary, thus it is not done by default.